# MonoDevelop Adds Character When Pasting

Tags: mono, monodevelop, paste

I'm using MonoDevelop 2.8.2 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 and when I cut and paste code, MonoDevelop adds a character at the end of the pasted text. The character repeats the next character after the paste. For example, I have "apples, oranges, pears)". I copy ", oranges" and paste after "pears", I get "apples, oranges, pears, oranges))" instead of "apples, oranges, pears, oranges)" i.e. the right parenthesis gets duplicated after my paste. Any ideas why its adding the character or how to turn it off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This cannot be, by any means, a feature. So please go use the right tool for the right job: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com/enter_bug.cgi?product=MonoDevelop

Answer (score 1):

IIRC this was a bug in the on-the-fly code formatter, whch is off by default, did you turn it on in MD prefs?

Have you tried using a newer version of MD, e.g. 2.8.5?

Comment: Ah. Yes it is on. Seems like that's the default with the version of MD Unity ships with its application. I tried MD 2.4 and 2.8 and both had the problem. Other mac apps weren't doing this. I restarted my Mac and the problem went away (for now).